# Maven and gwt project

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I m new user. I need a maven project using gwt dependecy. Which archetype i can use?Project as New GWT web application and after build maven nature is better then maven project with gwt archetypes?

Comment: have a look at these  http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1vSx8aDXk

Answer (score 4):

See:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven
- https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes (these are mine; [introductory blog post](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/announcing-gwt-maven-archetypes-project))
- https://github.com/branflake2267/Archetypes

I'd recommend **not** using the archetype from the gwt-maven-plugin. It's OK for people who already master GWT and Maven but definitely needs some polishing. The gwt-maven-plugin has a lot of good ideas, badly executed; my recommendation is to only use it for its `compile` and `generateAsync` goals, and possibly `mergewebxml`, and run DevMode from your IDE (Eclipse with the Google Plugin for Eclipse, or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition). `gwt:run` works OK though if you prefer plain Maven, but it really works best for single-module Maven projects, which I don't recommend with GWT.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of the gwt-maven-plugin.

Comment: Duh!! We use this approach and arrived at it by trial and error over last couple of years for GWT project with 70+ maven modules, 100 odd screens and fragment count over 100's . I am glad to know the usability/issues we faced were not just ignorance on our part. We finally could use it for only compilation. Maybe will give devmode a  try.

Answer (score 0):

I have an [old recipe for working with GWT and Maven](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/02/working-maven-3-google-app-engine-plugin-with-gwt-support/), that should just need some minor editing of versions of plugins to get it working with the latest versions.

I always start with Maven, generate my project structure, then import that into my IDE, starting at the IDE and going backwards is just asking for a world of pain. So hand building your structure, or better yet using an Archetype is the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 0):

We simply start with GWT sample/example project pom and work our way upwards/downwards from there. If we need more features from dependencies we add or if we need lesser features we drop the dependencies provided in the sample files.

You can find the latest sample pom files in GWT Trunk [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples).

- dynatablerf
- validation
- mobilewebapp

Note - We do update **plugin** version in the pom files to access some more bleeding edge stuff.